# From custom dockerfile to kubernetes deploy with an apache started

Tags: apache, docker, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

I have a dockerfile where I build an apache web server with some custom configurations etc.

Executing the Dockerfile I create an image that could be used in a deployment yaml file using Kubernetes. 
Everything is working properly but after deployment, my apache service is down in every container of every pod.

Obviously I can access in every container to execute an /etc/init.d/apache2 start but this solution is not very smart..

So my question is: how can I set my custom apache to be running during the execution of the deploy yaml file?

PS: I tried this solution: with the dockerfile I created a docker container then I accessed on it and I started apache. Then I created a new image from this container (dockerfile commit + gcloud image push) but when I deploy the application I always find apache down

Comment: It would be useful to share the CMD/ENTRYPOINT in Dockerfile, logs from POD in Kubernetes deployment.

Answer (score 0):

Well, first things first - I would very much recommend just using the [official apache2 image](https://hub.docker.com/_/httpd/) and then making your custom configurations from there. They're documentation states this in the following paragraph:

> **Configuration**
>
> To customize the configuration of the httpd server, just COPY your custom configuration in as /usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf.

```
FROM httpd:2.4
COPY ./my-httpd.conf /usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf
```

However if you're dead-set on building everything yourself; you'll notice that inside of the [Dockerfile](https://github.com/docker-library/httpd/blob/6d50d7f89f4d8bc6a6a3f86d892e254f4d6bfd8b/2.4/Dockerfile#L144) for the official image they are copying in a BASH script and then setting this as the `CMD` option. This works because when running a Docker container you should be running a **single process**; this is why, as you stated, running it from it's service is a bad idea.

You can find the script they're running [here](https://github.com/docker-library/httpd/blob/6d50d7f89f4d8bc6a6a3f86d892e254f4d6bfd8b/2.4/httpd-foreground), it's very short at 7 lines - so you shouldn't have too much trouble figuring out where to go from here.

Best of luck!

Comment: Hi thanks for your suggestion. Unfortunately I have to use a legacy apache version with some custom build configuration so I cannot use an official apache2 image. Anyway I tried some solutions and the one that is working is simply this line to add at the end of the Dockerfile: 

CMD /etc/init.d/apache2 start && tail -F /var/log/apache2/access.log

Comment: @suikoy That's a bad way to go about it; you're attaching yourself to the init process and the log file and not the Apache process. You'll run into issues later. What version of Apache do you need? The official image goes as far back to 2.0. Not to mention, you'll run into security vulnerabilities the farther back you go.